# Using Android Studio

Tags: performance, android-studio

I am trying to design and write code (in Android) of a simple app that displays the product and sum of two numbers that have been input by a user but a have several errors.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](//idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

package com.example.multiply;  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.TextView;  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {      private Button Add;     private EditText Num1;     private EditText Num2;     private TextView result;      @Override     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);          Add = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);         Num1 = findViewById(R.id.etNum1);         Num2 = findViewById(R.id.etNum2);         result = findViewById(R.id.tvAnswer);           Add.setOnClickListener(new view.onclicklistener()(                 @Override                         public void onclick(View view)(                                 int number1 = integer.parseInt(num1.getText());                                 int number2 = integer.parseInt(num1.getText());                                 int sum = number1 + number2;                                 result.setText("Answer:"+String.valueOf(sum));     } });         }         }